# Strange iOS tableView/CALayer crashes

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, calayer

My app started crashing after long time in background right when I launch it again.
The problem of course is when it wasn't killed - only when it was in the background.

the log is:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32858a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337013b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x336f9bf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30504a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3068f06c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30502e36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30502e8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30502f5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3068dc84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3351048a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
10  Foundation                      0x326ea56c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 56
11  UIKit                           0x31bc3a82 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 666
12  UIKit                           0x31bc3764 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 28
13  UIKit                           0x31bbc0c6 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 930
14  UIKit                           0x31bbb276 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 134
15  UIKit                           0x31b675f4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 20
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3347defc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
17  QuartzCore                      0x33351bae -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 114
18  QuartzCore                      0x33351966 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 178
19  QuartzCore                      0x333571be CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 206
20  QuartzCore                      0x33356fd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
21  QuartzCore                      0x3335004e CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 50
22  CoreFoundation                  0x334e7a2e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
23  CoreFoundation                  0x334e945e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
24  CoreFoundation                  0x334ea754 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3347aebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
26  CoreFoundation                  0x3347adc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
27  GraphicsServices                0x311a5418 GSEventRunModal + 108
28  GraphicsServices                0x311a54c4 GSEventRun + 56
29  UIKit                           0x31b90d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
30  UIKit                           0x31b8e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
31  Vento                           0x00002c64 main (main.m:14)
32  Vento                           0x00002c0c start + 32
```

Any idea where to start digging?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the log to see the exception detail.

Run the static code analyzer over your code. It may find the bug for you.

Comment: Isn't it the `EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)`? and what's the static code analyzer? where can I find it? Thanks.

Comment: The stack trace looks like there's an exception, so you may have some log text. To do static code analysis, in Xcode 4 choose the Product menu and select "Analyze". This will typically thoroughly embarrass you, show what a terrible coder you are, and make you question how your program ever ran. The menu should be renamed "Humble me".

Comment: Yeah I know this tool already, nothing's wrong there except missing methods of some protocols of mine which have no connection to my problem, as far as I can see. Any other idea? Thanks!